# How to go about fetching the key names from prototypes of a object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'am trying to find the keys in an object in javascript.

```
_relatedRecords: Object {  }
_store: Object { _source: {…}, _cache: {…}, __OWNER__ember15756161564291396511861164__: {…} }
identity: Object { type: "something", id: "1" }
<prototype>: {…}
  constructor: function Policy()​​
  description: ​​
​  modifiedtime: 
​  name: 
  <get description()>: function CPGETTER_FUNCTION()​​
  <set description()>: function CPSETTER_FUNCTION()​​
​​  length: 1
​  name: "CPSETTER_FUNCTION"
​​​  prototype: Object { … }
  <prototype>: function ()
  <get modifiedtime()>: function CPGETTER_FUNCTION()​​
  <set modifiedtime()>: function CPSETTER_FUNCTION()​​
  <get name()>: function CPGETTER_FUNCTION()​​
  <set name()>: function CPSETTER_FUNCTION()​​
  <prototype>: Object { … }
```

This is the object. When I use `Object.keys()` I get the key values as `['_relatedRecords','_store','identity']` but the values that I need to fetch are the keys `['description','modifiedTime','name']`.

I can access them using `object.name` or `object.description` and I get these values alright. But how  do we go about fetching what all are the keys in the object.

Comment: try `for(var prop in your_object)` it iterates over all properties including prototype

Comment: yeah...that would give me all the keys. but how to get only keys of non function elements? since prototype has a lot of keys it would be better if i could find a specific type

Comment: you can test if the property value is of type function to filter it, i don't think there is any simpler way to do it(might be wrong)